# about SQL Row ascending order

Tags: php, mysql, row

I have this `2 table` in database in sql

TABLE1:

```
USER id | state| TYPE | time |

 1      | 1    | 1    | time |
 2      | 1    | 2    | time |    
 3      | 1    | 2    | time |    
 4      | 1    | 2    | time |    
 5      | 0    | 1    | time |    
 6      | 0    | 1    | time |
```

TABLE2:

```
id |USER id| run

1  | 3     | 7       
2  | 1     | 5       
3  | 1     | 5        
4  | 4     | 8       
5  | 2     | 6       
6  | 2     | 6       
7  | 3     | 7     
8  | 3     | 7       
9  | 3     | 7        
10 | 3     | 7       
11 | 2     | 6       
12 | 4     | 8    
13 | 4     | 8       
14 | 1     | 5       
15 | 2     | 6        
16 | 2     | 6   
17 | 5     | 9      
18 | 4     | 8
```

I am printing this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE state != 0
```

it will print row this way

```
USER ID 1
USER ID 2    
USER ID 3    
USER ID 4
```

But I want to `ascending` this `by count`

```
WHERE, Count = num of row of TABLE2
```

Where user id=1 or 2 or..N

Here:

```
count of USER id 1 = 3    
count of USER id 2 = 5   
count of USER id 3 = 5    
count of USER id 4 = 4
```

Now i want to ascending

Table 1 where high count to low count from table 2 and high run to low run

```
USER ID 3   
USER ID 2  
USER ID 4   
USER ID 1
```

Using PHP AND MYSQLI

Please help me

Comment: Very ill written question, adding more and more rows from the db doesn't help people to understand your question. Next time please be more specific with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.id, count(t2.id) as t2_count
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.`user id` = t2.`user id`
group by t1.id
order by t2_count desc
```